# go install failure (but does not contain package golang.org/x/tools)

Tags: go

**Problem**:

When I run the command: `go install golang.org/x/tools@latest`

I get the error: `go: golang.org/x/tools@latest: module golang.org/x/tools@latest found (v0.1.12), but does not contain package golang.org/x/tools`

This started after upgrade from go 1.16 to go 1.18.

**Background**:

I have a pre build Docker image with go installed where I want to execute go commands, in this specific Docker it is go `mockgen` commands being executed creating gRPC and rest mocks.

Comment: `go install` requires a package. `golang.org/x/tools` is a module containing multiple packages.

Comment: So I have to figure out what sub-packages are used and then install them one by one?

Comment: It's sounds like all you want to execute is `mockgen` so why not install just that?

Comment: Try to use `go clean -modcache`

Comment: How do I specify a specific package inside this? Since it fails when I try, this is the same with gomock.

`go install github.com/golang/mock/gomock@latest`

`gomock is not a main package`

@mkopriva

Comment: @AndersBreid https://github.com/golang/mock#go-116

Comment: I will try only installing mockgen since that worked, not sure why the other modules was added previously (I thought mockgen required them).

Comment: @AndersBreid note the difference between `gomock` and `mockgen`. One is a plain, importable package. The other a `main`, executable package. You cannot *install* a non-main package. e.g. you cannot install the `net/http` package, you cannot install the `strconv` package. You can ONLY install `main` packages. Like `mockgen` for example.

Comment: @AndersBreid you can download and then import non-main packages into your code. But you cannot install them. Use [`go get`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Add_dependencies_to_current_module_and_install_them) to add such dependencies to your project.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `go install golang.org/x/tools/...@latest` if you want the packages within.

You can do the same thing with packages in mock:

```
go install github.com/golang/mock/...@latest
```

Comment: This seems to only install the dependencies specified in x/tools/go.mod file.

Comment: Well that should install all packages in that module. The docs for both `install` and `package` describe the behavior of `...` matching.